# How to conveniently subscribe to multiple recently declared resources?

Tags: puppet

How do I conveniently trigger a refresh on some resource upon a change in one of many other resources (possibly of various resource types) that were declared nearby, in puppet 4?

E.g.

```
# these resources
resource_type1 {...}
resource_type2 {...}
resource_type2 {...}
resource_type2 {...}
resource_type3 {...}

# should refresh this when changed
service {...}
```

I know I could list each resource in `subscribe`, and use resource collectors in it; but I'd like something more fitting for the chronically lazy.

---

I considered using a with block, but this doesn't work:

```
with() || {
  # these resources
  resource_type1 {...}
  resource_type2 {...}
  resource_type2 {...}
  resource_type2 {...}
  resource_type3 {...}
}

~>

# will refresh this when any of them have changed
service {...}
```

Only the last resource within the with block triggers a refresh.

You can test this for yourself using:

```
with() || {
  file { '/etc/test':
    content => 'Change this and notice it does not trigger',
  }
  file { '/etc/test2':
    content => 'foo',
  }
}
~>
exec {'/bin/echo triggered':
  refreshonly => true,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Puppet 4, while still leading to a good deal of boiler plate, a robust way of doing it is to use a class to group the resources:

```
class config {
  resource_type1 {...}
  resource_type2 {...}
  resource_type2 {...}
  resource_type2 {...}
  resource_type3 {...}
}

class { 'config': }
~>
service {...}
```

When part of a class, you'll want to add a `contain` as well ([here's why](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_containment.html#the-contain-function)), like so:

```
class foo {
  class { 'foo::config': }
  ~>
  service {...}

  contain 'foo::config'
}
```